# Telling git to use credential-osxkeychain

Tags: git

I am setting up git on my brand new Mac laptop according to these instructions:

https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

I am at the part where I tell git to use the osxkeychain credential helper

```
$ git config --global user.name "cspears2002"
$ git config --global user.email "cspears2002@yahoo.com"
$ git credential-osxkeychain
usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain \
> "$(dirname $(which git))/git-credential-osxkeychain"
mv: git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory
```

Do I even need to do this?  This is what I get when I run 'git config --list'

```
unknownc8e0eb148153:~ christopherspears$ git config --list
credential.helper=osxkeychain
etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as `git-credential-osxkeychain` is on your path, you really don't need to move it.  The issue is you have a `>` on the command-line... that's wrong.  You want:

```
$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain \
    "$(dirname $(which git))/git-credential-osxkeychain"
```

Better yet might be:

```
$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain "$(git --exec-path)"
```

After that, it should work.

Comment: Have the same issue, this did not solve it. I got the following output from the terminal `git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory`

Comment: @StenW Where is your git-credential-osxkeychain installed?  What does `git --exec-path` return?

Comment: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core

Comment: @StenW Is that also where git-credential-osxkeychain is installed?  Can you try moving it to `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: THx for responding, it will take me a minute to locate the file.

Comment: @StenW Perhaps you don't have `git-credential-osxkeychain` installed?  I believe the Mac binaries on the [Git website](http://git-scm.com/downloads) have osxkeychain.  You probably want to be using them anyways.  There were definitely some good bug fixes made since the one shipped with OS X.

Comment: Ok, I was an idiot and had two sets of git-credential-osxkeychain on my system. No wonder it did not work. The answer above worked great!